# Variable reset after await async Task

Tags: c#, winforms, async-await

I've got a windows forms app where the code for the form contains this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool testBool;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await new Form1().Run();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(testBool);
    }

    private async Task Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(testBool);
        testBool = true;
        Console.WriteLine(testBool);
    }
}
```

What I've noticed is that the result I get in the Console is

```
false
true
false
```

Where I would expect it to be

```
false
true
true
```

What is happening to `testBool` during this process? Is there a way I can preserve the value of this variable after `Run()` is complete?

Comment: You are doing `new Form1().Run()` - the new instance has its own `testbool`. Did you mean to make it static, or just `await Run()`?

Comment: You should go ahead and put that as the answer @Blorgbeard - I was about to post one, but you have it already in your comment. Basically derekantrican, you are instantiating a new `Form1` and calling the `Run` method of that new object, which will print out `false` then `true`, then when it returns from that, it writes the original `Form1` instances value of `testBool` which is still `false`.

Comment: @gmiley no, I'm too lazy to post an actual answer - I'd say go ahead, but looks like we were beaten to it.

Comment: @Blogbeard I'm officially an idiot. Thanks, that solved the problem. (And, yes, please put that as the answer so I can mark it as the solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to your question, you are accessing two different instances of your `Form1` class.

You are instantiating a new `Form1` and calling the `Run` method of that new object, which will print out `false` then `true`, then when it returns from that, it writes the original `Form1` instances value of `testBool` which is still `false`.

You may want to define your class as `static`, or at least provide a public static field, or private static with a public static field accessor property or function.

Answer (score 1):

`testBool` is a instance field, every `Form1` will have a different ones. If you want them to share the same `testBool` field, mark it as [`static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/98f28cdx.aspx) :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    static bool testBool;
}
```

### static (C# Reference)

> Use the static modifier to declare a static member, **which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object**. The static modifier can be used with classes, fields, methods, properties, operators, events, and constructors, but it cannot be used with indexers, destructors, or types other than classes. For more information, see Static Classes and Static Class Members (C# Programming Guide).